# How to pass Jenkins variables to Packer?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, hashicorp-packer

In Jenkins it is set like:

```
environment {
  VARIABLE_1 = credentials('variable-1')
}
```

In packer how am I meant to do this, I've had a brief idea how to do it but it never seems to pick up the value:

```
provisioner "powershell" {
environment_vars = ["VARIABLE_1={$env:VARIABLE_1}"]
inline           = ["Write-Host \"Secret Text is: ${Env:VARIABLE_1}\""]
```

So my question is, what's the best way to pass through this variable and ensure packer picks this up from Jenkins?

I have tried the above but I have also tried changing the environment variable format to no avail.

I was expecting the secret text value from Jenkins to be imported into Packer(HCL format).

Comment: When you use double-quoted string, Groovy string interpolation will be done first. Either escape dollar like `\$` or use single quotation marks, so Groovy doesn't interpolate: `['Write-Host "Secret Text is: ${Env:VARIABLE_1}"']`. The latter is usually recommended to prevent script injection.

Comment: So the part you've asked me to use single quotation marks is in Packer  ['Write-Host "Secret Text is: ${Env:VARIABLE_1}"']

It seems the part which doesn't work declaring the variable from Jenkins into packer unless I am understanding your answer wrong?

Just to add I'm declaring the variable like so:

stage('Example Step') {
      steps {
       powershell '$VARIABLE_1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "${env:VARIABLE}" -AsPlainText -Force'
      }
     }
I've done that to make sure that its saved as a value in powershell so that I can retrieve this later in packer but doesn't seem to work

Comment: I see. The problem is that each call to `powershell` from jenkins creates a new sessions, so any variable you define in powershell will be removed, when powershell script returns. Write to stdout with powershell and capture result in groovy variable: `stage('Example Step') { steps { script { env.VARIABLE_1 = powershell returnStdOut: true, script: 'ConvertTo-SecureString $env:VARIABLE -AsPlainText -Force' } } }`

Comment: Sure I can give that a go, what exactly are we aiming for in the stdout?

Is it to print the value of the variable to confirm Jenkins is passing this through?

Comment: In my example `ConvertTo-SecureString` already writes to stdout, because it is neither captured into a variable nor redirected. So powershell step will return this output and then we store it in env `VARIABLE_1`.

Comment: ok I see, so does that mean the variable name in PowerShell is declared as "${env:VARIABLE_1}" or will it be declared as $VARIABLE_1? 

I think the key also is I need to ensure that the variable is correctly declared within the powershell script which packer uses.

The first being that if its an environment variable then you add 'env' first.

Comment: "${env:VARIABLE_1}" is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not work for whatever reason. It literally makes the value of the variable env:VARIABLE_1 instead of the secret text credential in Jenkins.

It seems the secret is not ever actually being 'stored' in the variable when declaring on packer :(